# Best practices of state management in Django

Tags: django

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    STATE1 = 1
    STATE2 = 2
    STATE3 = 3
    STATE_CHOICES = (
        (STATE1,"state1"),
        (STATE2,"state2"),
        (STATE3,"state3"),
    )
    .
    .
    state = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STATE_CHOICES, default=1)

    def save(self):
       pass

    def method1(self):
       pass

    def method2(self):
       pass
```

The thing I would like to do; if state1 to state2 trigger method1, if state2 to state1 trigger method2, state2 to state3 trigger method3 etc.. how do I code without using many "if statement"? I want to write clean code.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make a function dictionary according your state and its function. Then you can call function via this dictionary in save method. It looks like this;

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
STATE1 = 1
STATE2 = 2
STATE3 = 3
STATE_CHOICES = (
    (STATE1,"state1"),
    (STATE2,"state2"),
    (STATE3,"state3"),
)
fn_dict = {
    "state1_state2" : state1,
    "state2_state2" : state2,
    "state3_state1" : state3,
}

.
.
state = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STATE_CHOICES, default=1)

def save(self):
    pre_saved_model = MyModel.objects.get(id=self.id) 
    self.fn_dict[pre_saved_model + "_" + self.state]()

def state1(self):
   pass

def state1(self):
   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use django signals. It's probably most cleaned way than override model instance save. For example you can try `pre_save` signal:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def handle_state(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # call method based for instance state
```

If you want to use "if statement" you can map your states with methods into dict and then get it by state:

```
STATE_METHODS = {
    STATE1: method1,
    ...
}
```

Also you can get instance methods using `getattr` built-in function and call it:

```
method = getattr(instance, f'method{instance.state}')
result = method()
```

Comment: It's always up to you how to orgonize you models but i'd like to advice you to use simple if statement if you have not so many states and if you have a lot of states then think how to unify you handlers and use only a signal instead a lot of model methods.